# How to remove "No Network" alert in my PWA on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, progressive-web-apps

When my iOS device is not connected to a network, the alert below pops up in my Progressive Web App when opened. How can I remove this to give my PWA a more native feel?

[image: PWA Popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the `web app manifest` component found in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-progressive-web-app-architectures#components).

> When connecting to a network for the first time, a web browser reads the manifest file, downloads the resources given and stores them locally. **Then, if there is no network connection, the browser uses the local cache to render the web app while offline.**
>
> ***Note:** Do not confuse this with the older **.manifest** file used by AppCache. PWAs should use the service worker to implement caching and the web app manifest to enable "add to homescreen" and push messaging.*

Here are some additional links for reference:

- [Service Worker: handle requests when offline to send them when online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510547/service-worker-handle-requests-when-offline-to-send-them-when-online?rq=1)
- [Offline web application using beforeunload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816167/offline-web-application-using-beforeunload-event)
- [Progressive Web App: offline cache does not work on Android, it works on Chrome dev Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733419/progressive-web-app-offline-cache-does-not-work-on-android-it-works-on-chrome?rq=1)